# Does Burrowing's extra damage affect non-attack damage and where inside/outside Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Burrowing's effect states:

> Deal 1 extra damage on Tokyo. [...]

**Does this mean**,

- "Deal 1 extra damage [to the Monster] on Tokyo."; or
- "Deal 1 extra damage [when your Monster is] on Tokyo."

I believe it is the former, because of the wording on **Urbavore**, "when dealing any damage **from Tokyo**." Although, it might have been shortened due to lack of space.

**Does Burrowing increase the damage from a non-attack?**  For example:

> {6} Acid Attack: Keep; Deal 1 extra damage each turn (even when you don't otherwise attack).
>
> {3} Fire Blast: Discard; Deal 2 damage to all other monsters.

Answer (score 2):

According to [iello](https://iello.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1118479-king-of-tokyo-card-burrowing), who wrote the rules for the [French](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63034/king-of-tokyo-french-rules) and [English](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63033/king-of-tokyo-english-rules) versions of the game states that you deal extra damage when you are in Tokyo:

> Cost: 5 Energy.
>
> Type: Keep.
>
> Text: "Deal 1 extra damage on Tokyo. Deal 1 damage when yielding Tokyo to the monster taking it."
>
> - You deal 1 extra damage **when you are in Tokyo**.
> - You deal 1 damage when you yield Tokyo to the monster attacking you.

As to the second part, what about damage cards, [iello says this about Firebreathing](https://iello.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/1270494-fire-breathing):

> **Firebreathing:** "Your neighbors take 1 extra damage when you deal damage"
>
> *Q: Does fire breating activate when you deal any damage?*
>
> E.G. Burrowing "Deal 1 damage when yielding Tokyo to the monster taking it."
>   or only when attacking?
>
> **A: Anytime you do damage wether by attacking or using an ability.**

Under this reasoning, I would assume that Burrowing would deal extra damage from any card with an effect that deals damage.